# Can't run Grails app?

Tags: grails

When I try to run my grails app I got the following error:

```
Error 2012-11-30 15:35:57,948 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: com/lp/labs/scconnector/GitConnector
->> 2427 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1791 | getDeclaredMethods in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: com.lp.labs.scconnector.GitConnector
->> 202 | run      in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   247 | loadClass in     ''
|   2427 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
|   1791 | getDeclaredMethods in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-11-30 15:35:58,068 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: com/lp/labs/scconnector/GitConnector
->> 2427 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1791 | getDeclaredMethods in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: com.lp.labs.scconnector.GitConnector
    ->> 202 | run      in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
    |   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
    |   247 | loadClass in     ''
    |   2427 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
    |   1791 | getDeclaredMethods in     ''
    |   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
    |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
    |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    |   908 | run      in     ''

^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

and this is my build.config file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        compile 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:2.0.0.201206130900-r'
        compile 'SC-Connector:SC-Connector:1.0'
        compile 'AccountConnector:AccountConnector:1.0'


        // runtime
        runtime 'org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:2.0.4.RELEASE'
        runtime 'org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:2.0.4.RELEASE'
        runtime 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.2'
        runtime 'org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm:3.1.0.RELEASE'
        runtime 'org.springframework.ws:spring-oxm-tiger:1.5.10'
        runtime 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.12'
        runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1'
        runtime 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1'
        runtime 'xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1'

    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

I think the classes are on my class path so I don't think it is a class path problem. Do anybody have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide more info. What's the grails version? This is a fresh project? Did you already try `grails clean` and `grails compile`?

Comment: grails version is 2.1.1. I copied this project to another machine and it was working. I tried clean and run the project again but it still show the same error.

Comment: Can you post your buildConfig? `com.lp.labs.scconnector.GitConnector` is some private class? I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: It's something related with your jar in the lib folder, as @burt answered. grails run-war works?

Comment: I got: Error Exception occurred trigger event [CreateWarStart]: grails-app/migrations does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is `com.lp.labs.scconnector.GitConnector` in a jar file in the lib directory? If so, run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get Grails to add it to the classpath

Comment: Yes it is in a jar file in the lib folder. I run this command and nothing changed

Comment: Did you run from the commandline or your IDE? To get it recognized in STS you need to run Grails Tools|Refresh Dependencies to get STS to sync itself up with the Grails classpath.

Comment: Actually, looking closer you're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` which is different from `ClassNotFoundException` since it means the class is there, but a class that it depends on isn't. Are you missing other dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

maybe your problem may stem from other reasons, I had the same error and after consultation everywhere I suggested making a Grails-CLEAN and everything was solved.

Answer (score 0):

use command

```
grails clean-all
```

after that use:

```
grails refresh-dependencies
grails-compile
```

than run with

```
grails run-app
```